# init react-native rbenv version not installed

Tags: react-native, rbenv

When I create a new react-native project with `npx react-native init projectname`, it create a .ruby-version file in the new project folder with ruby version 2.7.5

But on the [react-native set up guide](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) under section "Ruby" there is a link to [the react-native repository](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/template/_ruby-version) that says the version of ruby should be 2.7.6

I ask this because I get the following error: `rbenv: version '2.7.5' is not installed (set by /Users/user/Documents/Projects/projectname/.ruby-version)` when I initialize the project.

If I change the global ruby version to 2.7.5 then it works...I just dont know why it defaulting to 2.7.5 instead of 2.7.6